# Onion and Layers Architecture real world example

Tags: architecture, onion-architecture, layered

Can you guys give me a real world small business case example where the Onion architecture would be a better choice than the 3 layered architecture?

Thanks,

Miguel

Comment: It depends on the project size. Simple projects that dont need unit testing and for example have 1-2 pages, single entity model, etc. then 3 layers would take less time to implement and still look well. For more complex cases - using IoC, decomposition (and as a possible implementation - Onion architecture) would be better choice.

Comment: Take a look at the following two articles: http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/onionsoftwarearchitecture.php and https://medium.com/@fbzga/clean-architecture-in-ruby-v2-d2293c78d4a6

Comment: @neleus projects that do not need unit testing? I have never heard of such category of projects. Onion architecture is a type of a layered architecture, some say that it is a layered architecture done right, with the most important advantage compared to the traditional 3 layered architecture being not leaking the data access infrastructure code into the upper layers.

Comment: Yes, in some cases project can do simple calculations and have minimal UI and it still can have value for business. For such case I don't think it's worth unit testing. Though I'm a fan of TDD, from my experience unit testing has some complexity threshold with negative business value. When project crosses the threshold the business value becomes positive.

Comment: Use onion architechture when testability if the most important concern. By 'testability', I mean the ability to write unit tests for any part of your code.